# eclipse display setting issue - how to display the last modified date time and person

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

How can I show the last modified date and time as attached image of left hand side. Thanks

[image]

I am using Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0) with the Subversive SVN plugin and tried to find in "Help" but no clues.

Comment: Which SVN plugin? Subversive or Subclipse? For Subversive, go to the preferences _Version Control (Team)_ > SVN > Label Decoration_, tab _Text Decorations_.

Comment: oh.. i see. I need to click the "..." button and select the required format.  Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the **preferences** (on Windows and Linux: *Window > Preferences*; on macOS in the application menu) ***Version Control (Team) > SVN > Label Decoration***, tab ***Text Decorations*** and use the **<kbd>...</kbd>** button to add the `{date}` variable.